# American ID requirements for indian domestic flights

Tags: air-travel, usa, india, identity-cards

I am an Indian with an American citizenship. I will be travelling in India with my family through domestic flights. I am wondering about the ID requirements for Indian domestic flights. Do I need to carry the american passport for ID purposes? Also, will there be issues in buying the tickets online and paying through Indian rupees in this case?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are also an Indian citizen? Do you have an Indian passport?

Comment: @Doc India doesn't do dual citizenship. In the past, the did a [PIO Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persons_of_Indian_Origin_Card), as of 2011 this has been merged with the [OCI Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizen_of_India#Overseas_citizenship_of_India).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure whether the fact that you're Indian yourself has anything to do with it, frankly.

I am an American citizen and have in the past purchased internal flights within India over the internet, paying in Rupees using my credit card issued by an American bank.  I flew from USA to the UK and then to India using my American passport.  I landed in Hyderabad, where I spent about two weeks on business.  I then flew an internal flight from Hyderabad to Bangalore - on leisure, attending a friend's wedding - and back to Hyderabad.  A couple of days later, I flew back to England.

On the internal flights, I used my American passport (which naturally had Indian visa to enter the country in the first place) as a proof of identity.  Nobody looked at the visa - all they looked at was the photo page in the passport.  I flew with Kingfisher Airlines at the time - but I don't think there's any difference, really.

To summarise, I had no problem buying tickets online and flying using my US passport as a proof of identity.

Answer (score 4):

As an American Citizen with Indian Origin I believe you are travelling to India without a Visa with the help of your (and your family members as well) [PIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persons_of_Indian_Origin_Card)(merged with OCI Card in 2011) or [OCI Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizen_of_India#Overseas_citizenship_of_India). That should be more than enough to embark the flight.

The Indian Embassy lists the [OCI Card](https://www.indianembassy.org/pages.php?id=20) as a valid Identity Proof for several tasks, even though it doesn't mention domestic flights, it should be sufficient.

For surety I will recommend carrying your passport along though, but I don't believe it will be necessary for domestic travel although it is mandatory while entering or leaving the country alongside your passport (with the lifelong U Visa in it).

Answer (score 1):

I am an American citizen and have travelled to India a couple of times in the past.  I have also flew internal flights - and used my American passport as the ID.  Nobody ever asked me for anything else.

Even though I had an Indian visa in my passport, nobody ever flipped the passport pages to check it.  They simply looked at the photo page and waved me through.